# Segmentation Fault When Parsing Char Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am working on a function that takes a string parameter (actually sending a char array from the main function, but don't think that makes a difference) in C, and parses the string to be stored in a linked list (it is an assignment for school) and am receiving a segmentation fault. I have added strings to be printed throughout the program in order to debug the program, because it relies on an input file, and I do not know how to start gdb with an input option.

This is what my function looks like:

```
Token * list_head = NULL;
    Token * current = NULL;
    char line_segment[MAX_PRINT_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
    int i, pos = 0; //In the for loop, we do not not to lose the pos in the array
    puts("in token.c, beginning segmentation");

    /***************************************************************************
     * Loop through the possibilites of the first character starting at the 
     * position located at the pointer (pretty sure this is still easier on the
     * memory and logically then enumerating all of the different symbols and 
     * types of chars that you will see.
     **************************************************************************/
    for(i=0; line_copy[pos] != '\0';){
            if(line_copy[pos] == 'a' || 'b' || 'c' || 'd' || 'e' || 'f' || 'g' ||
                                 'h' || 'i' || 'j' || 'k' || 'l' || 'm' || 'n' ||
                                 'o' || 'p' || 'q' || 'r' || 's' || 't' || 'u' ||
                                 'v' || 'w' || 'x' || 'y' || 'z' || 'A' || 'B' ||
                                 'C' || 'D' || 'E' || 'F' || 'G' || 'H' || 'I' ||
                                 'J' || 'K' || 'L' || 'M' || 'N' || 'O' || 'P' ||
                                 'Q' || 'R' || 'S' || 'T' || 'U' || 'V' || 'W' ||
                                 'X' || 'Y' || 'Z') //Identifier or Rw
                    do{
                            line_segment[i] = line_copy[pos];
                            pos++; i++;
                    } while(line_copy[pos] == //All letters of alphabet);
            else if(line_copy[pos] == '0' || '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' ||
                                      '6' || '7' || '8' || '9'){ //Number
                    do{
                            line_segment[i] = line_copy[pos];
                            pos++; i++;
                    } while(line_copy[pos] == '0' || '1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' ||
                                              '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || 'e');
            }
            else if(line_copy[pos] == " "){ //No token
                    line_segment[i] = '\0';
                    pos++;
            }
            else if(line_copy[pos] == "'"){ //String
                    do{ //We want to keep the first apostrophe for make_node
                            line_segment[i] = line_copy[pos];
                            pos++; i++;
                    } while(line_copy[pos] != "'");
                    pos++; //Don't want to start on the ending ' symbol.
            }
            else{ //Symbol
                    line_segment[i] = line_copy[pos];
                    pos++;
            }
            puts("line segmented, attempting node");
            printf("line segment: %s\n", line_segment);
            current = make_node(line_segment);
            memset(line_segment, '\0', MAX_PRINT_LINE_LENGTH);
            puts("attempting to add node to list");
            list_head = add_to_list(list_head, current);
            free(current);
            puts("node freed");
    }
    return list_head;
}
```

Comment: That big `if` condition doesn't do what you expected.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to use gdb with command line argument? Use `set args` command, google for its usage and debug the program yourself first.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [isalpha](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function from the `ctype.h` header, with that you could have written `if(isalpha(line_copy[pos]))` instead of the big non-functioning block you have now.

Comment: Thank you Yu and jpw; these helped a lot! Still pretty new to C, and knowing these functions makes it a whole lot easier to look at complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if(line_copy[pos] == 'a' || 'b' || 'c' || 'd' || 'e' || 'f' || 'g' ||
                             'h' || 'i' || 'j' || 'k' || 'l' || 'm' || 'n' ||
                             'o' || 'p' || 'q' || 'r' || 's' || 't' || 'u' ||
                             'v' || 'w' || 'x' || 'y' || 'z' || 'A' || 'B' ||
                             'C' || 'D' || 'E' || 'F' || 'G' || 'H' || 'I' ||
                             'J' || 'K' || 'L' || 'M' || 'N' || 'O' || 'P' ||
                             'Q' || 'R' || 'S' || 'T' || 'U' || 'V' || 'W' ||
                             'X' || 'Y' || 'Z')
```

You have to follow the actual C syntax. You can't make things up and expect them to work. You are ORing a bunch of letters, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that this was not equivalent to line_copy[pos] == 'a' || line_copy[pos] == 'b'. . . .

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`isalpha()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) and [`isdigit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)functions from `ctype.h`.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it a whole lot easier!